# Como hacer una textbox redondeada en visual studio windows forms?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Como hacer una textbox redondeada en visual studio windows forms?  en la ventana de propiedades no hay ninguna opcion como "corner" o "shape" y no encuentro una forma para hacerlo por codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe de forma nativa esta posibilidad, vas a tener que programar con [gdi](/questions/tagged/gdi) para darle forma, como en este ejemplo

[Textbox with rounded corners](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17453/Textbox-with-rounded-corners)

Pero la verdad es algo complicado, quizas si usas componentes de terceros como ser

[AltoControls](https://github.com/aalitor/AltoControls)

seria mas simple de implementar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este componente permite bordes redondeados en los textbox, puedes agregarlo por nuget

[AltoControls nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AltoControls/1.0.1)

Comment: y como puedo "instalar" esos componentes? perdón si es una pregunta obvia, soy nuevo en esto

Comment: lo mencione, lo agregas usando nuget, imagino que despues deberas agregar la libreria en la toolbox (desde la carpeta packages que crea nuget) para poder arrastrarla el form